# Gaul Divided into 3 fats

Tags: cookbook

There is a cookbook with at least two editions about French cooking based upon dividing the country into fat regions: butter, olive oil, and lard (?). I cannot find it on-line though I did previously. Do you know this book?
Many thanks!
+PAX!

Comment: The butter/olive oil split is a common one. Hopefully the lard will narrow it down.

Comment: Did Caesar write a  Cookbook? 

Answer (score 2):

Waverly Root (1966) "The Foods of France" ... is referenced in Sari Edelstein's "Food, Cuisine, and Cultural Competency for Culinary, Hospitality, and Nutrition Professionals" (2010) when talking about dividing France into butter, fat & oil.  ([see page 135](https://books.google.com/books?id=lj0CeaIIETkC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=gaul+culinary+fat+regions&source=bl&ots=IcT1lGjb_j&sig=0yqUTT_ac6rOsAlDDPalsG3IdPI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp2cDbru7LAhXH2yYKHa0JCBkQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=gaul%20culinary%20fat%20regions&f=false))

... but I suspect it's a typo for "Waverley Root" author of "The Food of France".

Comment: And 'fat' makes sense, as it would also include poultry fat (duck, goose, etc.), which are quite common in some French cooking.

Comment: That's it! Waverley Root, The Food of France. I've just bought it for a dollar plus shipping. Thank you so very much! Rhubarbcook. +PAX!